# iBeacons: "Accuracy" unit

Tags: objective-c, ibeacon, ios8.1

What is the unit in which core location framework gives the "Accuracy" (distance) for iBeacons. According to my knowledge it should be in Meters. But, in my app I have placed some beacons in distance of 19 Meters (63 foot) and the accuracy value of beacon from the framework is coming to be greater than 25 also sometimes.

Comment: apple documents it as: Indicates the one sigma horizontal accuracy in meters. Use this property to differentiate between beacons with the same proximity value. Do not use it to identify a precise location for the beacon. Accuracy values may fluctuate due to RF interference.

Comment: I want to know he distance between users device and my beacons and display message when user is a a certain distance from all the beacons.How can i do this? Also if my total distance is 19 m how come acrylic value be great than 19 +/- 5 meters is ok but with this much difference how can I use accuracy to display message :(.

Answer (score 2):

**The unit of `CLBeacon.accuracy` is in meters, but as you have witnessed, it is only a rough estimate.**  At short distances of 3 meters or less, the estimate will usually be within a meter.  At longer distances it can be off by 10 meters or more.

This error is due to radio noise, multipath and attenuation.  **Estimation errors are a fundamental limitation of the technology, so you must set expectations appropriately.**

Read more here: http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/12/04/fundamentals-of-beacon-ranging.html

Comment: do u mean to say that in my logic I should keep +/- 10 meters range of distance that I am receiving from iOS framework ?